# Multiple parameter transmission ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After the selection of the three lists, Courses, Series, Groups it is needed to generate an automatic tabel. 
after transmitting the function parameters, they take the same value .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 
     $('#CourseList,#GroupList,#SeriesList').on('change',function(){
        
   var Code_Course  = $(this).val();
   var Code_Group = $(this).val();
   var Code_Series  = $(this).val();
  
        if(Code_Course,Code_Group ,Code_Series{
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
               url:"page2.php",

             data: {Code_Course: Code_Course,Code_Group: Code_Group,Code_Series:Code_Series},
                success:function(html){
                    $('#table').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: When you use $(this).val() to obtain the value this will obtain the of one element not the value you want, instead of $(this).val() use var Code_Course = $("#CourseList").val() to obtain the value and the same for the other variables because $(this).val() only make reference to one value.

Answer (score 0):

See this the solution showed here working well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

CourseList
  <select id="CourseList">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
GroupList
  <select id="GroupList">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  SeriesList
  <select id="SeriesList">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      
     
         $('#CourseList,#GroupList,#SeriesList').on('change',function(){
            var f = document.createElement("form");
              var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
    i.setAttribute('name','Code_Course');
    i.setAttribute('value',$('#CourseList').val());
    f.appendChild(i);
              var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
    i.setAttribute('name','Code_Group');
    i.setAttribute('value',$('#GroupList').val());
    f.appendChild(i);
              var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
    i.setAttribute('name','Code_Series');
    i.setAttribute('value',$('#SeriesList').val());
    f.appendChild(i);
      
            
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                   url:"page2.php",
                  processData: false,
        contentType: false,
                 data: new FormData(f),
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#table').html(html);
                    }
                }); 
        });
        });

  </script>


</body>
</html>
```